# How to upload files/multiple files from Node in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, grid, webdriver

On my web automation i tried to use such code which does not work:

```
 WebElement El = driver.findElement((By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/label/span[1]/span")));
        ((RemoteWebElement) El ).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        El.sendKeys("~/Documents/Data/20_10MB/176H.jpg");
```

The problem is that it cannot find element. The element which located on the website have only Xpath. It does not have any other unique id.

I need to write test which will upload 1 or multiple files ( up to 10 000) or whole folder. How i can do this on mac?

Current set up is Hub which will invoke test on Node machines.
Robot does not work because it will automate keys on the local machine only. 
What is possible workaround?

Comment: Your xpath is complicated and brittle, no wonder its not finding element. Can you post short relevant html around the element you are trying to interact with?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're trying to handle wrong element as `span` is not what you need. Try below code:

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement((By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")));
El.sendKeys("~/Documents/Data/20_10MB/176H.jpg");
```

Comment: Question 1:
It tells "Path is not absolute".
But i dont need Absolute path, because each node will have different location of file , meaning that Node 1 will be /userMartin/testFiles and user 2 will be /userJoe/testFiles.
Is there is a way how node will inherit files from Grid? Or how i can use test without absolute path.Becauseuploading 5000 from Hub to Node and From Node To Web will take much longer then from Node to Web directly. How to use relative path instead of absolute "~/Documents/Data/20_10MB/176H.jpg"

And question 2:
How i can choose multiple files? Meaning 500+ files

Comment: 1. Well you can store all your test files on one remote server and make `HTTP-GET` request to download each file simply by name, but it seem to be little complicated and need web-traffic and more time. 2. Do you actually can upload more than 1 file at the time manually via `UI`?

Comment: I was using a Robot , but it will dont work in this case. Because it will only execute on local machine. Using robot i just point to one file and used cmd+A hotkey

Comment: You talk about **one** file, but are you able to upload multiple files manually at the time? Without using `RobotFramework` just as user

Comment: Just as user when i click "Upload" on web it opens Native Mac Upload Screen, where i can with Shift choose multiple files or use cmd + A to upload all of them.

Comment: If target `input` field has attribute `multiple`, then I guess you can try to send several files separated with comma

Comment: yes, but the problem that it`s a folder with over 5000 files, and almost all of them have unique name.

Comment: Did you try to set all of those names separated by comma as argument of `sendKeys()` ?